# Call prepare for segue on UITextFieldBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift

In My app I need to popup to  a datepicker on entering the text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a date picker and set it as your text field's input view. Refer this code.

```
var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.date = Date()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateTextField), forControlEvents: .valueChanged)
yourTextField.inputView = datePicker
```

Hope this helps.